# connect rails application to many databases

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3

lets say I have users, and each user belongs to some group. For security reasons I want to have separate database for each group. I imagine that objects User and Group are stored in one central database, and authentication is performed against this database, but all other objects connects dynamically to different database which is defined in Group object.

So question is: how do I connect dynamically to different database with my object depending on some parameters (ex. dbname)?

Answer (score 1):

you can use class method "establish_connection", but to be honest, I don't know if this can be called dynamically every time you need. I use it for models which connects to different database this way:

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "second_#{Rails.env}"
end
```

database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  username: web
  password:
  database: first_db
  pool: 5

second_development:
  ...
  database: second_db
  pool: 5
```

As far as I know, establish connection can be also called right with Hash containing the parameteres from database.yml, e.g.

```
establish_connection { :username => "web", :database => "..." }
```

But I don't know if this will be using connection pooling if you do it this way.

I also use it like that when I write script outside rails (just pure ruby with inclusion of the activerecord) and then I connect to db manually.

I hope this helps.

Regards, NoICE

Answer (score 0):

Use [MultiConfig](http://shadabahmed.com/blog/2012/09/18/introducing-multiconfig-gem-for-activerecord) gem I created to make this easy.

You could specify the configs in separate file like second.yml etc and then call:

`ActiveRecord::Base.config_file = 'second' # for all models`

or

```
SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.config_file = 'second'
end
```

This way it will be much easier to maintain and cleaner looking.

Comment: can I make it take data for different id from different database? I mean can I have parts of data of the same model in diifferent databases? Say, if ID < 1000 take it from database A, and if ID >=1000 take it from database B?

Comment: Not yet .. its just complete data from 1 db .. what you can do is dynamically change db . .Model.config_file = 'xxx' .. then find .. and then Model.config_file = 'database'